# How to disable child(RecyclerView) scrolling before parent(ScrollView) has completely scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. When I try to scroll to bottom, the RecyclerView(child element) scrolls to bottom before the parent starts scrolling. But what I want it, the parent should scroll completely before child starts scrolling. Here is my layout file. Can someone please guide me how can I achieve this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/user_activity_linear_layout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/blank_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recently_watched_recycler_view"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/blank_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I feel like i should warn you that scrolling views within scrolling views is nearly always going to give you problems with android, and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: I have read a lot of such warnings against scrollview inside a scrollview. Why is it considered a bad practice? My use case requires me to have such a layout.

Comment: Well if above is your actual layout why not just put `blank_layout` as the first item of the recycler view? This ofcourse assumes you want the recycler view to fill the scrollview which, by the xml you gave, it looks like you do.

If that is not the case why does it have to be in a scrollview in the first place?

Comment: Actually my actual layout has a Pager and each page of pager has recyclerview as its child. (I removed the pager here and replaced with recyclerview for simplicity)

Now, I did not put the empty space inside the recyclerview as 1st child because then there will be empty space between PagerTabStrip and recyclerview children. I want this emptyspace to be above PagerTabStrip. Any suggestions?

Comment: So then why does it need to be a scrollview if you just want the space above the tab strip?

Comment: I want to give a effect (like that of Artist profile page on Vevo App) where your pager starts after some space(having background image). Now as you scroll up, the Pager scrolls up and gradually tints the image in the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105419/discussion-between-bhaskar-and-joe-maher).

Answer (score 0):

Disable RecyclerView. Extend scrollview so that you will know when ot has reached bottom as bellow.

```
public class myScrollView extends ScrollView
{
    public myScrollView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
    public myScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context,attributeSet);
    }

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
{
    View view = (View)getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int d = view.getBottom();
    d -= (getHeight()+getScrollY());
    if(d==0)
    {
        //you are at the end of the list in scrollview 
        //do what you wanna do here
    }
    else
        super.onScrollChanged(l,t,oldl,oldt);
}
```

}

Once your scrollViewReaches bottom enable recyclerView. Give it a go. If you are not able to achieve what you desire using this method let me know.

Comment: Sure, Thanks! I will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) - it supports having nested scrolling enabled views (such as `RecyclerView`) inside of it. Make sure you are using [Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), which allows `RecyclerView` to measure itself based on its contents.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to find if  Support Library 23.2 is enabled for me. But I am not convinced if it is. I tried google but could not find how to ensure if it is enabled. Can you give some pointers how can I check?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're using Android Studio and Gradle, you'd check your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2' - I have this.

Comment: The dependency would be `'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, a typo. Thanks. I will try it now.